# What is the difference between a fully contained database & Azure SQL Single database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, self-contained

When a database is fully contained, it is having all the objects within the database boundary. It manages connection also at database level. [Contained Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)

I have few questions:

- If I host a contained database in Azure SQL Single DB then what is
  the difference between a Azure SQL single db and a contained database
  as Azure SQL single db ?
- Why do we have a separate offering as Azure SQL Single Db, when
  contained database also is something similar to it ?
- Does making a database as contained database will help in easier
  migration to Azure SQL single DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure speak, "single" is a deployment option that differentiates Azure SQL Database from Managed and Elastic Pools. There's really no difference from a containment perspective because Single and Azure SQL Database are one and the same.

Azure SQL Database inherently provides containment features like database-level user authentication. With on-prem SQL Server databases, one must opt-in for with `CONTAINMENT=PARTIAL`
to permit database-level authentication.

> Does making a database as contained database will help in easier migration to Azure SQL single DB ?

`CONTAINMENT=PARTIAL` permits database-level authentication in on-prem versions, facilitating migration of database security principals. As long as user database entities stay within the database boundary and one doesn't need features unavailable in contained databases (e.g. CDC), migration is typically easy.

A consideration, though, is that partially [contained databases implicitly use catalog collation `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations) whereas Azure SQL Database catalog collation must be either the chosen `DATABASE_DEFAULT` collation or `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. This is generally an issue only when case-sensitivity of object/variables names is desired.

Existing uncontained references can be identified by querying [`sys.dm_db_uncontained_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-uncontained-entities-transact-sql):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_uncontained_entities;
```

The above query will also identify dynamic SQL references that will need to be examined manually.

Comment: can you please elaborate, why Azure SQL Database is partially contained. Also, how can we tell whether a database is fully contained ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR, I didn't word my answer as clearly as I should have but what I basically meant is that contained features like database-level authentication are available by default in Azure SQL Database whereas on-prem databases require opting in with the `PARTIAL` containment option. You can identify uncontained entities with `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_uncontained_entities;`. I'm off to my day job now but will improve my answer when I get back.

Comment: Sure. thanks. Just wanted a clear explanation, so that it is helpful for others in future. I will accept the answer, once you have updated the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I have accepted the answer